# Chain of multiple where Active Record clauses not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I am fairly new to Ruby on Rails and ActiveRecord.  I have a database model named `location` which describes a point of interest on a map.  A location has a `location_type` field that can have three different location types (business, dispensary or contact).  A location also has an `owner_id` as well which is the `user_id` of the user who created the location.

In the controller the user requests all of their locations by providing their ID.  The dispensary and business locations are public so all users should be able to view them, while the contacts should only be shown to the user who is the owner of them.  Therefore I am tasked with creating an ActiveRecord query that returns all dispensaries and businesses in the database and all contacts that were created by that user.  I was trying to do this by chaining together where clauses but for some reason this has failed:

```
@locations = Location.where(:location_type => ["business", "dispensary"]).where(:location_type => "contact", :owner_id => params[:id])
```

Which generates this PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations"  WHERE "locations"."location_type" IN ('business', 'dispensary') AND "locations"."location_type" = 'contact' AND "locations"."owner_id" = 1
```

I suspect that this failed because the first `where` returns just the locations of type business and dispensary and the second `where` queries that returned data which has no locations of type contact within it.  How can I query for all dispensaries and businesses combined with a set of filtered contacts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chaining `where` calls like that will result in `AND`s at the SQL level. `where` can take raw SQL for an argument, in which you could explicitly add an `OR`, but parameterizing it properly is rather messy IMO (although it can be done). So, for this type of query, I think it would probably be best to drop down into using raw SQL with sanitized inputs (to guard against SQL injection).

i.e. something like this:

```
x = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection.prepare(
    "SELECT * FROM locations
     WHERE location_type IN ('business', 'dispensary') OR
           (location_type = 'contact' AND owner_id = ?)")
x.execute(params[:id])
x.close
```

This will select all items from the `locations` table where the `location_type` is either 'business' or 'dispensary', regardless of the `owner_id`, **and** all items where the location_type`is 'contact' where the`owner_id` matches the one passed in.

**Edit in response to comment from OP:**

I tend to prefer raw SQL whenever possible for more complex queries, as I find it easier to control the behavior (ORMs can sometimes do things that are less than desirable, such as executing the same query 1000 times to get 1000 entries instead of one SQL query once, resulting in terrible performance), however, if you'd prefer stay within the bounds of *ActiveRecord*, you can use the form of `where` that takes arguments. It'll be somewhat raw SQL, in that you need to specify the where clause yourself, but you won't need to get a `raw_connection` and explicitly execute -- it'll work within the framework of the *ActiveRecord* query you were doing.

So, that would look something like this:

```
@locations = Location.where("location_type IN ('business', 'dispensary') OR
    (location_type = 'contact' AND owner_id = ?)", params[:id])
```

See this [Active Record guide page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) for more info, *section 2.2*.

**Edit in response to follow-up question from OP:**

Regarding the `?` in the SQL, you can think of it as a placeholder of sorts (there's really no formatting to be done with it, but rather signifies a parameter goes there).

The reason it's important is that when a `?` is placed in the query and then the actual value you want to use is passed as an argument to `where` (and certain other functions as well), the underlying SQL driver will interpolate the parameter into the query in such a way that prevents *SQL injection*, which could allow for all kinds of different problems. If you were to instead do the interpolation yourself directly into the query string, you would still be potentially susceptible to *SQL injection*. So not only is `?` *safe* from SQLI, it's specifically intended to prevent it.

You can have a bunch of `?` in your query, as long as you pass the corresponding number of parameters as arguments after the query string (otherwise the SQL driver should error out).

Comment: Thank you for your quick response @khampson, I was trying to avoid using raw sql is this the best way to do this?

Comment: Sure, no problem. I added another alternative that works within the bounds of *ActiveRecord*.

Comment: Thanks man I am just trying to wrap my head around this the `?` just signifies that a parameter is to be placed there? Kind of like a formatted string? And I am guessing that this is also safe from SQLI?

Comment: Added an addendum to my answer.